# a straight line passing through a point lying at the interior of a circle intersects it twice

Tags: geometry

How could I show this proposition :

***a straight line passing through a point lying at the interior of a circle intersects it twice***

without using analytic geometry. I would like to use only Euclidean (Hilbert) geometry.

Comment: Can you prove the existence of at least one point of intersection? If so, the rest is easy.

Comment: if you ask this question I guess that must be possible, so I'm working on that!!

Comment: do you consider the plane as a metric space?

Comment: Every line through the point and the center intersect the circle. The segment from the center to the circle is larger than the segment from point to the circle under certain constraints.